# Use private C++ runtime library on linux

Tags: linux, gcc, dynamic-linking, libstdc++

In Windows, the dynamic loader always looks for modules in the path of the loaded executable first, making it possible to have private libraries without affecting system libraries.

The dynamic loader on Linux only looks for libraries in a fixed path, in the sense that it is independent on the chosen binary. I needed GCC 5 for its overflow checked arithmetic functions, but since the C++ ABI changed between 4.9 and 5, some applications became unstable and recompiling them solved the issue. While waiting for my distro [kubuntu] to upgrade the default compiler, is it possible to have newly compiled application linking to the new runtime, while packaged application still links to the old library, either by static linkage, or something that mimics the Windows behavior?

One way of emulating it would be to create a wrapper script

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(dirname $(which your_file)) your_file
```

And after the linking step copy the affected library but it is sort of a hack.

Comment: "The dynamic loader on Linux only looks for libraries in a fixed path" - no it doesn't, cf LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @Mat Yes, but it is independent on which image file it loads

Comment: You need to read a lot more about Linux dynamic linking.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I just think the currently installed compiler should not affect the behavior of other applications.

Comment: The compiler has nothing to do with that. It is a linker issue.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch True, but the compiler ships with an incompatible version of the library, and replaces the old one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rpath`.

Let's say your "new ABI" shared libraries are in `/usr/local/newapi-libs`.

```
gcc -L/usr/local/newapi-libs
    -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/newapi-libs
    program.cpp -o program -lsomething`
```

The `-rpath` option of the linker is the runtime counterpart to `-L`. When a program compiled this way is run, the linker will first look in `/usr/local/newapi-libs` before searching the system library paths.

More information [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html) and [here](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/rpath/).

You can emulate the Windows behavior of looking in the executable's directory by specifying `-Wl,-rpath,.`

[edit] added missing `-L` parameter and dashes before `rpath`.

Comment: For the OP: `-Wl,rpath` is an argument to the linker. The compiler just sees `-Wl` and pass the rest to the linker.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know: "-Wl, pass arguments to the linker ...". For completeness "-Wp, pass arguments to the preprocessor ..."